# How to compare date variable between 2 data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, rbind

sorry if my answers had been already asked, but I don't find any answer to my issue.
I have 2 dataframes which contain date.

This is my first dataframe.

```
LOT            TEST_DATE  
Q622207    2016-07-31 09:56:00
```

The second one is :

```
LOT            TEST_DATE  
Q640130     2016-11-30 08:18:00
Q640130     2016-11-30 08:18:00
Q640132     2017-01-17 05:17:00
Q640132     2017-01-17 13:43:00
Q640132     2017-01-17 13:43:00
Q640132     2017-01-17 13:43:00
```

I would like to compare my first dataframe with the second one,

And if the date of my first data frame doesn't have in the second, add this raw to the second.

I tried with an `if else` but it didn't work.

```
if(df2$TEST_DATE != lot$TEST_DATE){
  new<-rbind(lot,df2)
}else{
  print("Fail")
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just `rbind` both data frames as they are and then just remove duplicates?

Comment: thank you, i'm new in R and i didn't know this function. `new<-new[!duplicated(new), ]`   It works really well ;)